# “Juggling childcare” meaning

Tags: meaning

I found this word in an article

> juggling childcare

but I don’t understand its meaning. Is there any difference from just saying

> childcare

I tried to find it out by looking in a dictionary but I did not find an answer there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure if you put the entire sentence here, it would say something like "...the difficulty of juggling childcare and a job".  "Juggling childcare" doesn't mean anything alone; the phrase is "juggling X and Y" or "juggling X, Y, and Z"

It's a metaphor -- when you're trying to do multiple difficult tasks at once, it feels like you're juggling, constantly trying to keep all the balls in the air without dropping one by, say, forgetting to pick up the kids after school or failing to show up at work on time.

Answer (score 1):

Context matters here but I think the general meaning is that for some people who work outside the home, childcare can be a challenge.

Sometimes that means a "juggling act" between both parents, work schedules, and other child care providers.